# Hero's father in  Dragon Quest VII

Tags: dragon-quest-series

After beating Dragon Quest VII for PSX,including the secret dungeons I have an unanswered question about the story.

Was Sharkeye the hero's true father? Or is Borkano his descendant? Did they adopt the hero?

Both the hero and Sharkeye have half of the Aqua crest,and the game says Sharkeye's wife(?) had a baby, but it disappeared. It also says that the Aqua spirit protected her and the baby somehow. They look a lot like each other too.

Who is the hero's true father?

Answer (score 4):

The hero is Sharkeye's biological son.  When it became apparent that Orgodemir's forces were going to beat Sharkeye's (while Sharkeye's wife Anise was pregnant), the Aqua Spirit transported Anise's unborn baby to Borkano's wife's womb.  Borkano and his wife raised the hero thinking that he was their own biological child.

This explains Borkano's comment to the hero that the hero was born four months early but was born fully healthy.

This is discussed in more detail over on the [GameFAQs Message Board](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/197152-dragon-warrior-vii/43294433).